# 405 method not allowed json data not post

Tags: php, http, tcp, request

I am making simple form of posting details in php but got stuck while posting data from form to API but it is showing 405 method not allowed error. Please check my code below and let me know what is the issue in it. Might be I am doing some silly mistake, sorry if that is the case.

```
<form method="POST" action="#" name="checkout">

First Name <input type="text" name="firstName"/><br/>
Last name <input type="text" name="lastName"/><br/>
Email <input type="text" name="phone"/><br/>
Phone <input type="text" name="gender"/><br/>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>

</form>

</body>

</html>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $name = $_POST['firstName'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastName'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];

    $url11 = "https://api.rezdy.com/v1/categories/124095/products?apiKey=bb42962c78b34e02b879cc5463cb4648";
    $data['customer'] = array(
    'firstName'=>$name,
    'lastName'=>$lastname,
    'email'=>$phone,
    'phone'=>$gender
    );
    echo "<pre>";
    $json = json_encode($data);

    echo $json;
    echo "<br/>";
    function senddatat($url,$post)
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,"POST");
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,true); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json','charset=UTF-8 '));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
/*echo "<pre>";
var_dump( curl_getinfo($ch) ) . '<br/>';
echo curl_errno($ch) . '<br/>';
echo curl_error($ch) . '<br/>';
        curl_close($ch);*/
    return $result;
    }

    echo " ".senddatat($url11,$json);


}
?>
```

Comment: Why you are giving wrong label to your textbox? `Email <input type="text" name="phone"/><br/>
Phone <input type="text" name="gender"/><br/>`

Comment: The 405 http error code might refer to the api itself. Are you sure the executed method behind the api is working/callable?

Answer (score 0):

There is some errors in your form and post request. Also when you are calling ssl verified api. You need to pass ssl certificate with it. Or temporary you can disable it by `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to `FALSE`

Try this code:

```
<form method="POST" action="#" name="checkout">

First Name <input type="text" name="firstName"/><br/>
Last name <input type="text" name="lastName"/><br/>
Email <input type="text" name="email"/><br/>
Phone <input type="text" name="phone"/><br/>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>

</form>

</body>

</html>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $name = $_POST['firstName'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastName'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];

    $url11 = "https://api.rezdy.com/v1/categories/124095/products?apiKey=bb42962c78b34e02b879cc5463cb4648";
    $data['customer'] = array(
    'firstName'=>$name,
    'lastName'=>$lastname,
    'email'=>$email,
    'phone'=>$phone
    );
    echo "<pre>";
    $json = json_encode($data);

    echo $json;
    echo "<br/>";
    function senddatat($url,$post)
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,"POST");
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,true); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json','charset=UTF-8 '));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
/* echo "<pre>";
var_dump( curl_getinfo($ch) ) . '<br/>';
echo curl_errno($ch) . '<br/>';
echo curl_error($ch) . '<br/>';*/
        curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
    }

    echo " ".senddatat($url11,$json);


}
```

**EDIT**

**Note** : Error clearly tells that `Method Not Allowed it` means `POST` method is not allowed for `https://api.rezdy.com/v1/categories/124095/products` api you need to refer api doc

Comment: Sir Same error is happening.please check the below error       {"requestStatus":{"success":false,"error":{"errorCode":"1","errorMessage":"HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed"}}}

Comment: check your url its for getting product detail it will not post data

Comment: Ok Sir let me check

Comment: `'email'=>$phone,`   and    `'phone'=>$phone`  ???? i think you have to update the ans !!

Comment: @subrat Its clearly tells that `Method Not Allowed` it means `POST` method is nit allowed for `https://api.rezdy.com/v1/categories/124095/products` api you need to refer api doc

Answer (score 0):

**Check The Silly Mistakes First: This Is Your Fields:** `firstName,lastName,phone,gender`

```
<input type="text" name="firstName"/><br/>
<input type="text" name="lastName"/><br/>
<input type="text" name="phone"/><br/>
<input type="text" name="gender"/><br/>
```

**and What you get in the post request:** `firstName,lastName,email,phone` i dont know how you get the `email` in post request ????

```
$name = $_POST['firstName'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastName'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
```

---

### Updated:

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" name="checkout">

First Name <input type="text" name="firstName"/><br/>
Last name <input type="text" name="lastName"/><br/>
phone <input type="text" name="phone"/><br/>
gender <input type="text" name="gender"/><br/>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>

</form>

</body>

</html>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['firstName']) && !empty($_POST['lastName']) && !empty($_POST['phone']) && !empty($_POST['gender']) ){

    $name = $_POST['firstName'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastName'];
    $phone= $_POST['phone'];
    $gender= $_POST['gender'];

    $url11 = "https://api.rezdy.com/v1/categories/124095/products?apiKey=bb42962c78b34e02b879cc5463cb4648";

    $data['customer'] = array('firstName'=>$name,'lastName'=>$lastname,'email'=>$phone,'phone'=>$gender);

    echo "<pre>";
    $json = json_encode($data);
    echo $json;
    echo "<br/>";

    function senddatat($url,$post)
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,"POST");
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,true); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json','charset=UTF-8 '));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
/*echo "<pre>";
var_dump( curl_getinfo($ch) ) . '<br/>';
echo curl_errno($ch) . '<br/>';
echo curl_error($ch) . '<br/>';
        curl_close($ch);*/
    return $result;
    }

    echo " ".senddatat($url11,$json);


}
?>
```

Comment: from where you get $_post['email];label is missing in form

Comment: @Shanukk its not any email fields they typeo mistake, bcoz `array('firstName'=>$name,'lastName'=>$lastname,'email'=>$phone,'phone'=>$gender);` he store an phone inside and email field

Comment: i have already rectified it but still the same error was happened.

Comment: @subrat Check Now i updated the ans and if any error then tell me what error you saw

Comment: @RïshïKêsh i have already changed the email and phone as you said before but still the same error is happening

Comment: @subrat try to debug after `isset($_POST['submit'])` you get all the data in post request ?? verify it first

Comment: @RïshïKêsh Sir i have again executed the code which you have rectified but the same error is happening

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['firstName']) && !empty($_POST['lastName']) && !empty($_POST['phone']) && !empty($_POST['gender']) ){

   echo $name = $_POST['firstName'];
   echo $lastname = $_POST['lastName'];
   echo $phone= $_POST['phone'];
   echo $gender= $_POST['gender'];

}`  until this your code is work ?? after api getting you get the error !?

Comment: @Rishikesh Sir still i have not get the correct api